# C# Office.Interop.Excel How do I loop through the AutoFilter'd returned rows?

Tags: c#, autofilter

I have created the following AutoFilter:

```
excelRange = excelWorksheet.get_Range("G1");
excelRange.AutoFilter(Field: 7, Criteria1: "Part Number");
excelRange.AutoFilter(Field: 7, Criteria1: ">A*", Operator: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd);
excelRange.AutoFilter(Field: 4, Criteria1: "<2023-01-01", Operator: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd);
```

This reduced the rows down to a number let's say 935. How do I loop through the 935 rows produced by the AutoFilter?

Answer (score 0):

Using your range, call `SpecialCells` method with parameter `xlCellTypeVisible`.

```
var filteredRange = excelRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible);

foreach (Range cell in filteredRange)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Cell({cell.Column}:{cell.Row}) = {cell.Value}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked. It was posted on another forum:

```
Excel.Application app=new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx");
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
Excel.Range visibleCells = worksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(
                               Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible,
                               Type.Missing);                                                                       
 Excel.Range visibleCells = worksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(
                               Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible,
                               Type.Missing);
            foreach (Excel.Range area in visibleCells.Areas)
            {
                foreach (Excel.Range row in area.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Row!=935)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(row.Row);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            workbook.Close();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).